# Is there a command to export the current plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm creating a whole mess of charts, and would like to export the produced charts as PDF. It's possible to click 'export' in the Plot tab in rstudio and manually select "save plot as PDF", of course, and I'd prefer not to wrap every single one of my sections in `pdf()` / `dev.off()`.

Ideally I'd like a function that would take the currently-displayed plot in RStudio and save it with the parameters I'd like (format /filename / width / height).

Thoughts?

**Update**

As per @naught101's suggestion - for a 5x7 (inch!) pdf file which is a convenient size to be pasted into an A4 Word document, the following works well:

```
dev.copy2pdf(file="example.pdf", width = 7, height = 5)
```

Better yet, as an easily-called function with default dimensions:

```
dopdf <- function(filename = "dopdf.pdf", pdf.width = 7, pdf.height = 5) {
 dev.copy2pdf(file=filename, width = pdf.width, height = pdf.height)
}
```

While using `ggplot2` would have let me save using the `ggsave` function, `dev.copy2pdf` is a good generic solution (answering my original question).

Comment: Provide a reproducible example.  Why not have a single pdf() at the top of your script and a single dev.off() at the end of your script?  All plots created will be placed into a single nice pdf?

Comment: The R script I'm working with creates 15+ plots that are to be embedded in a Word doc; their size varies (hence a single PDF wouldn't help) and I would like to link the plot PDFs when embedded in the doc so that they update when I change the PDF (so need individual files). Plus, this has a lot to do with workflow - I tweak plots a lot while exploring data (which is coming in live from a GDocs form), and would like to be able to use the final version that I find in front of me. For examples, any plot will do ...

Comment: why don't you use a png() & dev.off() block before each plot ? I think you need to articulate your question better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`dev.copy2pdf`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/dev2.html). This allows you to copy the current device to a pdf, using the same arguments as [`pdf()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html). Works just as well for the base plotting functions as for ggplot2, (and any other plotting libraries that use the standard grDevice plotting devices, by the looks of it).

Answer (score 8):

If you use `ggplot2`, you can use the `ggsave` function to save the current plot. This function allows you to choose the width, heigth etc of the resulting plot (PDF, png, or other). When not using `ggplot2`, the `savePlot` function can be used to get similar functionality, although the man page suggests it only works on cairo `X11` devices.

Comment: `savePlot` doesn't seem to work in this case (RStudio on OSX 10.7), unfortunately; looks like the ggsave function would work well if I'd done everything in ggplot2 (which I'm now reading up on).